# Attempting to grab data from json with php returns nothing

Tags: php, json

I'm currently having an issue getting data from my json files in PHP.

What I got right now is

```
$jsondecoded = json_decode('[{"chat":{"username":"RobloxProtectorKing","message":":slender me","time":"2018-03-20 01:56:12"}}', true);

echo ($jsondecoded[0]->chat);
```

I'm attempting to get the chat information. But it doesn't echo anything. I've been attempting to figure out why this is but I sadly can't find it.

Comment: invalid json, missing `]` at the end.

Comment: Sadly thats not the issue. I fixed it and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three errors:

1) Missing ] at the end of the json.

2) You are using the "array assoc" option of json_decode, so it is not returning an object.

3) You cannot echo the chat object.

Try this:

```
$jsondecoded = json_decode('[{"chat":{"username":"RobloxProtectorKing","message":":slender me","time":"2018-03-20 01:56:12"}}]');

echo ($jsondecoded[0]->chat->username);
```

Comment: 4) `echo` is a construct, no need to wrap in parentheses.

Comment: Wow. Can't believe I'd miss such simple things. Thanks for the help Dionei, will come very useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
$jsondecoded = json_decode('[{"chat": {"username":"RobloxProtectorKing","message":":slender me","time":"2018-03-20 01:56:12"}}]', true);
```

Also, remember that you've used `true` as second parameter for `json_decode`, it means you're converting the result into a associative array, either remove that `true` or change your access to:

```
var_dump($jsondecoded[0]['chat']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid at end add ']' end of json string, and print array in php use print_r function. '[0]' use for get first element and ['chat'] use for get value of chat key

```
$jsondecoded = json_decode('[{"chat":{"username":"RobloxProtectorKing","message":":slender me","time":"2018-03-20 01:56:12"}}]', true);

print_r ($jsondecoded[0]['chat']);
```

output will like

```
Array
(
    [username] => RobloxProtectorKing
    [message] => :slender me
    [time] => 2018-03-20 01:56:12
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example from a template I have. Hopefully it helps.

```
<?php
/* Status Codes

return 0 = Nothing to Update (n/a)
return 1 = Successful Insert Query
return 2 = Database Connection refused
return 3 = MySQL Query Error OR Wrong URL Parameters */

/* Disable Warnings so that we can return ONLY what we want through echo. */
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// First get raw POST input
$raw_post     = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Run through url_decode..
$url_decoded  = urldecode($raw_post);
// Run through json_decode...
// false to allow for reference to oject. eg. $column->name instead of $column["name"] in the foreach.
$json_decoded = json_decode($url_decoded, false);

$pk_line_item_id  = (strlen($json_decoded[0]->value)  > 0 ? $json_decoded[0]->value : null);

// INCLUDE DB CONNECTION STRING
include 'php_pdo_mysql_connect.php';

// SQL INSERT query...
$stmt = $link->prepare(" SELECT * FROM tbl_xyz ");

//$stmt->bindParam(':pk_line_item_id', $pk_line_item_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);   // INT

// Execute this SQL statement.
$stmt->execute();

// Fetch & Populate the single returned in var $resultSet.
$resultSet = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
// Returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0. 
// https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.php.doc/doc/t0023505.html

// If the search record was found, populate it on the html table.
if (($resultSet !== false) && ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)) {

// Set JSON headers
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

// Encode entire $resultSet array to JSON.
$json_encoded = json_encode($resultSet);
// Ready to return as JSON to client side JQuery / Java Script...

echo $json_encoded;

}

?>
```